# Android in app purchase hanging the application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an Android app that launches the purchase flow from a dialog within a Fragment.

The purchase flow is launched like:

```
config.getIabHelper().launchPurchaseFlow(
          faActivity, 
          sku, 
          Constantes.SOLICITUD_COMPRA,
          faActivity.mPurchaseFinishedListener, 
          purchaseIdentifier);
```

Where:

- config.getIabHelper() returns an instance of the IabHelper class as implemented in the google documentation (the same used in the trivialgame example)
- faActivity is the parent activity of the fragment
- Constantes.SOLICITUD_COMPRA is a positive integer
- mPurchaseFinishedListener is the listener, which is implemented in the parent activity.

So the current flow should work like:

1. Make a purchase.
2. Acknowledge that the purchase was bought.
3. Update the UI so that it enables the user to use the purchased item rather than to buy it.

However it works like:

1. Make a purchase.
2. The application freezes and stops.
3. When the application is relaunched, the inventory is queried and the UI gets updated.

It seems like mPurchasedListener is never called.

To make it more weird, everything seems to work fine with test responses. I am testing the app in alpha with real responses and that is where the trouble appears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i've had this issue before my self and there are multiple things that could be causing this issue.

Firstly, please make sure that you've done the following for aplha stage testing and that you've added all the required permissions and aidl files.

**1)** Are you using a version of the app you've put on your device through android studio? If so, this could be your issue. Usually you'll receive a message notifying you that the version of the app you're using isn't compatible with in-app purchases. Alpha stage apps are actually downloaded from the google play store. You should have set up a google group that has access to a specific link that will allow you to open the google play store and download your alpha stage app.

**2)** Are you connected to the internet? Obviously launching a purchase flow with a real SKU ***will*** require an internet connection to the google play servers.

**3)** Did you set up this in app product up as a **managed product?** For simplicity, i highly recommend doing so.

if you've correctly set up everything as I mentioned above and are still having a problem, then likely it's an issue with how you setup and attempt to use your purchase flow.

***Here's the steps i took to launching a purchase flow from within a fragment***

- Instead of setting up the IAB Helper in the fragment, set it up in the faActivity Class. We will then call the purchase flow method within the faActivity class from within the fragment in which you're viewing via Dialog Box.

### This is how i set up in app purchases :

### ***faActivity.java***

IabHelper mHelper;

In the oncreate method :

```
 String base64EncodedPublicKey = "your in app purchase key";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
                                   {}});
```

Add these methods as well :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {


        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
        }
    }
};


public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure


        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

  IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {
            /*The purchase was successfully consumed, now update the 

 //ui/award the user with their purchase (I suggest storing the fact that 

 they're premium or whatever within the shared prefrences of your app)*/

                }};

  String ITEM_SKU = "";
 //Launching the purchase Flow
public void makeThePurchase() {
 //Assign the SKU Name of your managed product
    ITEM_SKU="premiumMembership";
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10000,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}
```

Now in your fragment, use this code to show a dialogBox asking the user if they wish to purchase the product and launch the purchase flow if they wish to do so

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new      AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    LayoutInflater inflater =   getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
                            .setPositiveButton("Purchase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    ((faActivity)getActivity()).makeThePurchase();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setTitle("Purchase");
                    builder.setMessage("Purchase premium membership?");
                    builder.create().show();
```

And that is how i managed to launch a purchase flow from within a fragment. I'm sure there is a better way to do so, but when setting up the purchase flow from within the fragment, i always recieved issues as well when trying to launch a purchase.

Hopefully this solved your issue!

Good Luck!!! :)

NOTE: The code i've listed above is setup to consume the purchase (meaning that the fact that they own it won't show up when querying the inventory) Like i said above although, if you're not concerned about the users having to repurchase their items/premium purchases in the occurance of them getting a new device or uninstalling your app, then just keep track of what they've purchased and consumed within the shared preferences by calling this code below from within the onConsumePurchasedFinished listener :

```
 SharedPreferences pref =      getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("hasBoughtPremium",true);
                    editor.apply();
```

Then when reloading the app, check to see if they own the premium item :

```
 SharedPreferences pref =   getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Boolean isPremium = pref.getBoolean("hasBoughtPremium",false);
```